# Resize windows locked randomly from some edges or corners

Tags: macos, window-manager

Usually I can resize any window from any edge or corner but sometimes when I grab certain edges or corners of a window it is frozen and will not allow me to resize.  But if I hunt around the other edges or corners there is always one that works.

I have no problem *grabbing* any edge or corner so the mouse cursor changes to the resize cursor, but at random times it just won't resize.

There are some windows with size intentionally locked or with minimum size ... I'm not talking about those.  My problem is with normal windows that CAN be resized, but only by overcoming this problem and finding the random corner that works.

(MacOs 10.15.7 MBP 13" 2017)

**Response to questions**:

- This happens with any app, I have not noticed any pattern that it is only with some apps.
- It is not always the same corner that freezes or that still works.  Maybe the bottom right corner always works, I'll have to pay closer attention to that.
- I do use multiple screens, and I use them as a single space.  I have tried to relate this problem to multiple screens but I cannot.  For completeness there is a similar behavior (not problem) related to multiple screens: *If any part of a window is in the main screen (the one with the Apple Menu), when grabbing a part of the window in another screen you cannot move or resize the window so its top edge goes beyond the top of the main screen.*.   I understand this, it is consistent, and it is not the problem I am describing here.
- I rarely use full screen because I don't like the way it behaves with two very large monitors used as a single space.
- I am using an Apple Magic Mouse.
- Regarding fullscreen and mouse: On rare occasions I undock my laptop and use its trackpad and screen only.  On those occasions I do almost everything in fullscreen and I don't resize windows much so it's hard to say whether the problem goes away if I use the trackpad.  The Magic Mouse is generally flawless.

Comment: Is this app-specific, or can it happen to any app? Is it always the same corner? If so, which? Do you use multiple screens? Do you use fullscreen on any affected apps?

Comment: Are you using a mouse or other external pointing device, or just the built-in trackpad?